# Can an arithmetic circuit have multiple outputs?

Tags: circuits, polynomials

An arithmetic circuit relates to calculating the value of a polynomial given some inputs.

But is it still considered a circuit if the DAG corresponds to the evaluation of multiple polynomials that share nodes?

Consider $f(x, y) = 3x^4 * y^3$ and $g(x, y) = 3x^4 * y^2 + x^2$. $f$ and $g$ share the node corresponding to the expression $3*x^4*y^2$. Would expressing this relation in a DAG still be considered a circuit?

Comment: Circuit in which context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a circuit has one output: it computes a single function.  Therefore, your question does not come up, because we cannot have a circuit that outputs both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$: that would be two outputs / two functions.

If you had a circuit that outputs a single value, say $h(x,y) = f(x,y) * g(x,y)$, then yes, you could certainly build a DAG with one node for the value $3x^4 * y^2$.  This node would would have an edge to the node for $f(x,y)$, and it would also be used in computing $g(x,y)$, so it would also have an edge to the node for $g(x,y)$.  That is all legal.

You can of course consider a type of circuit with multiple outputs, even though this is not typical, and then yes, it is fine to have one node for the value $3x^4 * y^2$, which is "shared".